# JoeCo Blackbox Recorder - Anyone used one?

Tags: recorder

Hello,

I am looking at upgrading a traveling rig I use for live events and I am looking at exchanging 24 rack units of backup recording devices for this 1 rack unit JoeCo Blackbox Recorder:

http://www.joeco.co.uk/main/BBR_introduction.html

Has anyone used one?

This would go on as my backup recorder to a Pro Tools I/O.

I had one in to test but this was in optimum recording environments on my line conditioned power. I am curious if it holds up under actual live, dark back stage, heat of the moment recording situations?

This could also be a good unit for you guys to bring with you on big gunshot recording sessions.

Thanks!

- Ryan

Comment: @Utopia:  I've heard great things.  Are you planning to use this for bars/clubs, auditorium shows, or a mix of both?  Not that I know what difference it would make, I'm just being nosy :)

Comment: @g.a.harry International Awards shows mainly, with a live music show here and there. The cool thing is that you can daisy-chain more on each other to get more and more inputs.

Comment: have not used one, but they sure are pretty!!